# Why my tabs are not expanding in TIMEFORMAT?

Tags: bash, quoting, time

I need to measure the running time of an application, so I'm messing with TIMEFORMAT in order to print short format with the maximum precision available.

From the Bash Refence Manual:

> TIMEFORMAT
>
> The value of this parameter is used as a format string
>   specifying how the timing information for pipelines prefixed with the
>   time reserved word should be displayed. The ‘%’ character introduces
>   an escape sequence that is expanded to a time value or other
>   information. The escape sequences and their meanings are as follows;
>   the braces denote optional portions.
>
> %% A literal ‘%’.
>
> %[p][l]R The elapsed time in seconds.
>
> %[p][l]U The number of CPU seconds spent in user mode.
>
> %[p][l]S The number of CPU seconds spent in system mode.
>
> %P The CPU percentage, computed as (%U + %S) / %R.
>
> The optional p is a digit specifying the precision, the number of
>   fractional digits after a decimal point. A value of 0 causes no
>   decimal point or fraction to be output. At most three places after the
>   decimal point may be specified; values of p greater than 3 are changed
>   to 3. If p is not specified, the value 3 is used.
>
> The optional l specifies a longer format, including minutes, of the
>   form MMmSS.FFs. The value of p determines whether or not the fraction
>   is included.
>
> If this variable is not set, Bash acts as if it had the value
>
> $'\nreal\t%3lR\nuser\t%3lU\nsys\t%3lS'
>
> If the value is null, no timing
>   information is displayed. A trailing newline is added when the format
>   string is displayed.

But, whenever I set TIMEFORMAT the tabs and new lines are not expanding:

```
rafael@lip ~/time-tests $ time ls

real    0m0.099s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.002s
rafael@lip ~/time-tests $ TIMEFORMAT='\nreal\t%3lR\nuser\t%3lU\nsys\t%3lS'
rafael@lip ~/time-tests $ time ls
\nreal\t0m0.002s\nuser\t0m0.000s\nsys\t0m0.002s
```

Why? and how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell does not interpret any backslashes inside single quotes.  If you want backslashes to be interprested use the `$'...'` construct, as in:

```
TIMEFORMAT=$'\nreal\t%3lR\nuser\t%3lU\nsys\t%3lS'
```

From `man bash`:

> ```
>    Words of the form $'string'  are  treated  specially.   The  word
>    expands  to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as
>    specified by the ANSI C standard.  Backslash escape sequences, if
>    present, are decoded as follows:
>           \a     alert (bell)
>           \b     backspace
>           \e
>           \E     an escape character
>           \f     form feed
>           \n     new line
>           \r     carriage return
>           \t     horizontal tab
>           \v     vertical tab
>           \\     backslash
>           \'     single quote
>           \"     double quote
>           \nnn   the  eight-bit  character  whose value is the octal
>                  value nnn (one to three digits)
>           \xHH   the eight-bit character whose value is the hexadec‐
>                  imal value HH (one or two hex digits)
>           \uHHHH the  Unicode  (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value
>                  is the hexadecimal value HHHH (one to four hex dig‐
>                  its)
>           \UHHHHHHHH
>                  the  Unicode  (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value
>                  is the hexadecimal value HHHHHHHH (one to eight hex
>                  digits)
>           \cx    a control-x character
>
>    The  expanded  result is single-quoted, as if the dollar sign had
>    not been present.
> ```

By contrast, with plain single quotes, no characters are given any special treatment, as `man bash` explains:

> ```
>    Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the literal value
>    of  each  character  within  the  quotes.  A single quote may not
>    occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.
> ```

Thus, inside plain single quotes, a backslash is just a backslash.

Answer (score 1):

You must use an dolar sign `$` in assignment to `TIMEFORMAT`:

```
TIMEFORMAT=$'\n\nreal_test\t%5lR\nuser_test\t%5lU\nsys_test\t%5lS'  
time ls
....

real_test   0m0.006s
user_test   0m0.000s
sys_test    0m0.004s
```